# Creating overlapping divs

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Im trying to recreate a design however im having trouble with the overlay portion. My thought process is to have a div for the menu bar, a div for the globe, and a div for the header text. However, positioning these to seemingly overlays is causing me trouble. I tried to use zIndex but that doesn't seem to help.

[image]

I currently have this: 
[image]

The way my code is set up in my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Globe from './Assets/Globe_.png';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Components/Nav';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import WhatWeDo from './Components/WhatWeDo';
import { Container, Box, BoxTitle, BoxText } from "./Components/GlobalStyles";
import './App.css';

//Make bg gradient in the global style
//remove image resizer dependency and flexa 

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient">
    <Container>
      <div>
        <Nav />
          <img src={Globe} className="responsive" alt="Unicron" />
        <Header />
        <WhatWeDo />
      </div>
      </Container>
      </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: just use the image as a background image?

Comment: I think setting the globe image as a background using css will make things easier to handle.

Comment: Either the background image suggestion, or to use css/scss to position element, make the parent relative and the children relative and use z-index to pout them where they are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order for them to be layered you either need to position them all absolute and then order them with either translating on the x and y axis and z-index, or using the top/bottom/left/right properties, I wouldn't recommend that because it's going to be tough to manage. It can also end up making the elements at the back inaccessible!

As the globe is a background image you could make that a background image over the top of a linear gradient like below, then your title and text can take up the space over the top of the background in their expected position within the normal document flow, and you can adjust them from there.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #fee807;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/250) 80% -35% no-repeat;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/250) 80% -35% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        rgba(254, 232, 7, 1) 0%,
        rgba(240, 118, 75, 1) 37%,
        rgba(212, 62, 128, 1) 70%,
        rgba(129, 86, 158, 1) 92%
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-gradient">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menu 1</li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="globe">
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      <h1>MAKE THE CONNECTION</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg-gradient {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  background: yellow;
}

.menu ul {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.menu ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.globe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}

.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.menu {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.globe {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.text {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```